# How to remove empty array from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

Here is the multidimension array, and I want to remove the empty array in it.

```
$exclude1=array(

array(

    [0] => Last Updated: Thu Apr 21 17:03:23 2016 PST

)
Array

(

    [0] => 

)

Array

(

[0]=>

)

Array

(

    [0] => MODEL: MODEL_NC

)

)
```

I want to remove empty arrays. I have tried this:

```
$exclude1=array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $exclude1));
```

but it is not working.

Comment: when i use array_filter it is giving Warning: array_filter(): The first argument should be an array

Answer (score 1):

Your current array values are following:

```
$exclude1 = array(
    array("Last Updated: Thu Apr 21 17:03:23 2016 PST"),
    array(""),
    array(""),
    array("MODEL: MODEL_NC"),
);
```

**See the output of current array. it's look like the follwoing :**

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($exclude1);
```

**Output will be:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Last Updated: Thu Apr 21 17:03:23 2016 PST
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => MODEL: MODEL_NC
        )

)
```

**Use array_filter and array_map**

```
$newArray = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $exclude1));
```

**Check the final output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Last Updated: Thu Apr 21 17:03:23 2016 PST
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => MODEL: MODEL_NC
)
```

So it will remove empty array from your previous multidimensional array.

**2nd Way**

```
function array_remove_null($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_null($value))
            unset($array[$key]);
        if(is_array($value))
            $array[$key] = array_remove_null($value);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

**3rd Way:**

```
$arr = array_filter_recursive($arr);
$arr = array_filter($arr);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: i m getting warning on this line Warning: array_filter(): The first argument should be an array

Comment: I have a question which is $exclude1 contain one `array` and there are 4 arrays as element right?

Comment: same warning as before  @Sumon Mahmud

Comment: may be problem with php version i have.. my php version 5.0.5

Comment: Check this link. The same code also working there  `http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e8b167603b010995c139d8c44d58be61527ee7a`

Comment: any other solution other than that?

Comment: this way is not helpful for you? or getting any problem?

Answer (score 1):

In you code, you wrongly used the array_filter, you can check its [menual](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.array-filter.php).

> array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag =
>   0 ]] )

So you can use this way.

```
<?php
$exclude1=array(
    ['Last Updated: Thu Apr 21 17:03:23 2016 PST'],
    [null],
    [null],
    ['MODEL: MODEL_NC']
);
unset($exclude1[1][0]);  //this make the array empty as you question.
unset($exclude1[2][0]);
var_dump($exclude1);
$exclude1=array_filter( $exclude1, function($v){return count($v) == 0 ? false : true;});
var_dump($exclude1);
```

and the output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "Last Updated: Thu Apr 21 17:03:23 2016 PST"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "MODEL: MODEL_NC"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "Last Updated: Thu Apr 21 17:03:23 2016 PST"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "MODEL: MODEL_NC"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.array-filter.php) like this way:

```
$exclude1=array_filter( $exclude1, function($v){return count($v) == 0 ? false : true;});
```

Comment: it is giving eror at that line Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: Could you explain what this does?

Comment: i m reading html table from html page and i m putting it in an array. which has an empty elements as mentioned above. after this i want to pad one string to this array elements which are not empty using unshift.

Comment: i m getting it as mentioned above after reading the html page.

Answer (score 0):

To remove empty arrays from an array you should be able to just do:

```
$newArray = array_filter($exclude1);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: php version 5.0.5

Comment: @sudarshannayak Yeah, my example won't work prior to 5.3. I've updated my answer to include something that should work for you.